# mapping stft rows back to frequencies

Tags: python, fft, librosa

I am using the Librosa lib to perform an stft. This results into a matrix with n_fft+1 rows which represent certain frequency bins.

I am definitely not an expert in this field! But as I understand the lowest possible frequency coming out of an fft is the Rayleigh frequency (F_rayleigh), and the highest frequency is the Nyquist freq. The frequency resolution F_res = (sample freq) / n_fft.

When I create a spectogram of the stft, the first row of the stft ranges between 0Hz and F_res! I always assumed the whole thing starts between F_rayleigh and (F_rayleigh + F_res). This was confirmed by an expert.

Can somebody tell me which frequency range is represented in the first row of the stft. I got an expert saying 'it starts with F_rayleigh' and a plot saying 'it starts at 0Hz'.

Thanks

Cspr

Comment: to become self sufficient just feed into the FFT call a known signal ... say 800 Hertz then observe what the freq bins say

Answer (score 0):

Use [librosa.core.fftfrequencies](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.fft_frequencies.html) to get the frequencies for all the bins.

Be careful to pass the same parameters that you use for your stft() call.